# Why have the XKCD cartoons in The Pod Bay stopped loading?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Monday's cartoon appeared only as a link, instead of loading as a graphic the way it usually does.

Today's cartoon link is broken, it loads a 404 message.

We need our XKCD. The cartoons are starred remarkably often, and have sparked chatter a number of times.

I've resorted to crude copy/paste methods to put them up like we are used to. But some change in chat code must have happened that caused this, so this post is partly so the dev team knows about it. We'd like our XKCD served the way we are used to, please. Thanks.

Comment: This is a bug report for xkcd, their API glitched today, "publishing" a comic before it was available. The link works now, but the time for onebox has passed.

Comment: @zaq Alright, i emailed the webmaster for the xkcd site. Thanks.

Comment: **All**: I've reopened and retagged as discussion instead of bug, so that we can track Kim's progress of seeking a solution from xkcd.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I didn't receive a reply to my email to the webmaster of XKCD, but the cartoon now posts like it used to, so one way or another it has been handled.

I choose to assume that the webmaster and Randall Munroe talked it over, clicked the link in the email to The Pod Bay, read the thread for a while and agreed that it is a charming place and they are happy we like Randall's cartoons so much, fixed the RSS feed, and then browsed the questions on Space Exploration over tea and cupcakes until they fell asleep in front of their monitors.

Update: 
The problem reappeared the following Friday, so I sent another email to the webmaster, davean. Today he responded

> Hopefully this will be better for you with the Wednesday update. It is
>   possible 404s were being cached when they shouldn't be.

Thus, tomorrow hopefully the comic will appear with its former instant glory, without me copying and pasting it.

Comment: Yes, it did. :)

Comment: Good job - persistence pays off.